# Looking for notation of set of all entries of some matrix?

Tags: matrices, notation

I'm busy writing my thesis, and I'm looking for some concise notation to denote the supremum of the matrix entries of, say $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. How should I do this?

Looking for something like
$$\sup_{a_{i,j} \in A}|a_{i,j}|$$
but the notation $a_{i,j} \in A$ in reality doesn't make much sense in my opinion. What else can I do?

EDIT: Even more ideally I want to denote $\sup_{a_{i,j}\in (A-B)}|A - B|$, but I might just introduce general notation for the "norm" to simplify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defined quantity is not a "norm", it **is** a norm (not an operator norm though and not sub-multiplicative). I'm not aware of a standard notation for this quantity, but $\|\cdot\|_M$ or $\|\cdot\|_{\max}$ look suitable.

Comment: Haha, thanks for that. At first I thought triangle equality wouldn't hold but I just wrote thing down and found out I was very wrong. The notation you mention is indeed the kind of unambiguous I was looking for.

Comment: BTW woudln't it be easier to write $\|A\|_{\max}=\max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$? The second notation in the edit does not make much sense, probably you wanted to have $|a_{ij}|$ as the argument of the $\sup$, which however could be confused with the elements of $A$ and not of $A-B$.

Answer (score 0):

Although not really **a** notation but a combination of notations, the quantity in question is $\|\operatorname{vec}(A)\|_\infty$.